# Get DataItem in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate, dataitem

Is there a way to get the actual DataItem of a DataTemplate. More specifically, I have a custom button which I use in a datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate1">
    <custom:SampleButton />
</DataTemplate>
```

I use this in a listview to bind to a collection. I would like to pass a reference to the actual DataItem that is being bound. Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate1">
    <custom:SampleButton BoundItem="{Binding DataItem}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Is this possible? How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You will find your DataItem in `DataContext Property`. There is no need for any additional property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to the data being used in data template. Here is an example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate1">
     <custom:SampleButton BoundItem="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

More details here (see Specifying the Path to the Value section):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#creating_a_binding

The idea is that inside the data template all elements in their DataContext reference the item to which data template is bind to. And {Binding} construct without Path simply binds to the DataContext.